# пару вопросов по решению к задаче

Tags: javascript, prototype, декоратор, this, return

По заданию: Добавьте всем функциям в прототип метод defer(ms), который возвращает обёртку, откладывающую вызов функции на ms миллисекунд. Понятно,только то что строка 3 привязывает контекст и аргументы к возвращаемой обёртке, которые берутся из замыкания

Непонятно почему  в коде  this сохраняется дважды? В строке (1) сохраняется задерживаемая функция, но почему тогда строку  с аргументами context(2) перенесли в возвращаемою функцию? Почему не объявили эту переменную перед return?При этом во второй строке контекст вроде как равен underfined

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
  var f = this; // (1)
  return function() {
    var args = arguments,
      context = this;  // (2)
    setTimeout(function() {
      f.apply(context, args); // (3)
    }, ms);
  }
}

// проверка
function f(a, b) {
  alert( a + b );
}

f.defer(1000)(1, 2);
```

Comment: "во второй строке контекст вроде как равен underfined" - это Вы как выяснили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что параметры для суммирующей функции `function f(a, b)` появляются только во втором вызове. То есть в вызове анонимной функции, возвращенной из `defer`.

Контекст во втором вызове, сохраненный в `context`, - это `window`.

Comment: а в строгом режиме разве контекст не равен   underfined  ?

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl в строгом - да

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl `undefined`